# ¿Cómo calcular días laborales entre dos fechas en dataframe python?

Tags: python, pandas, date

Buen día, necesito calcular del número de días transcurridos entre dos fechas, y que el resultado sea solo en días hábiles y/o laborales (Sin Sábados ni Domingos), actualmente tengo lo siguiente:

```
#DIFERENCIA DE FECHAS 'Fecha1' - 'Fecha2'
df['DIAS_TRANSCURRIDOS'] = (df.Fecha1 - df.Fecha2) / pd.Timedelta('1 day') 
df.head()
```

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Y que se hace con los feriados?

Comment: Es para que no los cuente en la diferencia de fechas.

Comment: Si te entiendo, el tema es el criterio, lunes a viernes se consideran hábiles en casi todo el mundo, pero los feriados nacionales en los que no se trabaja, ¿cómo los quieres considerar para esta pregunta? por que varía un poco la solución en función de esto.

Comment: Vale, me serviría mucho poder estimar la diferencia de fechas en donde solo se tengan en cuenta los días hábiles. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más sencilla si estás usando `pandas` y `numpy` es usar: [`numpy.busday_count()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html#numpy-busday-count). Por ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import date

# Generamos un ejeplo de datos 
date1 = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2019-1-1 12:00:00', periods=7, freq='M'))
date2 = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2019-6-18 21:45:00', periods=7, freq='W'))
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Start_date = date1, End_date = date2))

# Calculamos diferencias de días hábiles
df['diff_days'] = df.apply(lambda row : np.busday_count(row['Start_date'].date(),row['End_date'].date()),axis=1)

print(df)

           Start_date            End_date  diff_days
0 2019-01-31 12:00:00 2019-06-23 21:45:00        102
1 2019-02-28 12:00:00 2019-06-30 21:45:00         87
2 2019-03-31 12:00:00 2019-07-07 21:45:00         70
3 2019-04-30 12:00:00 2019-07-14 21:45:00         54
4 2019-05-31 12:00:00 2019-07-21 21:45:00         36
5 2019-06-30 12:00:00 2019-07-28 21:45:00         20
6 2019-07-31 12:00:00 2019-08-04 21:45:00          3
```

Eventualmente, está función, te permitiría definir el parámetro `holidays` para especificar días adicionales no laborables (por ej. feriados)

Comment: Me ha sido bastante útil, era lo que necesitaba, agradezco tu amable colaboración.